# How to cv2.imshow images stored in Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, opencv

I have 2 folders of 10 images each, I have loaded them into Numpy arrays and concatenated them (original individual np array shape : `10 128 128 3`, concatenated np array shape : `20 128 128 3`). Now I want to loop through 20 times and cv2.imshow each image, eg, 1st '1 128 128 3',then '2 128 128 3' and so on. But how do I feed such a shape to cv2.imshow?

My code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

first_images = np.array([cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("/filepath/*.png")])
second_images = np.array([cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("/filepath/*.png")])


num_of_first =first_images.shape[0]
num_of_second = second_images.shape[0]

image_array = np.concatenate((first_images,second_images),axis=0)

for image in range(image_array.shape[0]):
```

May be I could do something like 
    single_image = image_array(image,,,)
and then reshape this to 128x128x3? But I'm not sure how to do that.

EDIT :

Tried `cv2.imshow(image_array[image, :,:,:])` to get

> TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found

I used cv2.imwrite instead and was able to get what I wanted. The question remains how to get cv2.imshow to work.

Comment: Your error is `image_array` is a `numpy.ndarray`-  you should use square brackets to index it. Not sure if this will resolve your problem.

Comment: @FChm in that case I get error `IndexError: index 128 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 128`

Comment: That is because the indices run from 0 to 127 for this axis. 

I imagine using `cv2.imshow(image_array[image, :, :, :])` will work.

Comment: haha..looks very matlab-y. So it gave error `TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found`. Tried image_array[image, , , ] too, doesn't work.

Comment: If `image_array` is 4d, `image_array[0]` is 3d, and its `len` with the size of the 2nd dimension of `image_array`, 128, not the number of images.  `image_array[image,128,128,3]` would return a single point, if it wasn't for the fact that 128 is too large.  `image_array[i, :,:,:]` returns a single 3d array.

Comment: @hpaulj yes I realised that. I tried `cv2.imshow(image_array[image, :, :, :])` and got error : `TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found` as I mentioned in above comment

Comment: What arguments does `cv2.imshow` expect?  The problem isn't with the `image_array` indexing, because that's not a function call.

Comment: @hpaulj you are correct, I used `(image_array[image, :, :, :])` with `cv2.imwrite` and it worked fine. I think cv2.imshow is always a bit problematic, I'll try understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use "shape" with numpy to get array size instead of "len".